# I am trying to run OTB segmentation and I am getting output polygons that are too big

Tags: qgis-processing, polygon-creation, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation, otb-applications

I am running segmentation in QGIS Orfeo Toolbox on a MacBook pro. The first few times I ran segmentation, the results were satisfactory (the image was segmented with many small polygons). When I tried to run a new multi spectral image in the same project I began to get strange results (the image was segmented into 4-5 large polygons). Since then, I have been unable to get any result but these weird large polygons. I have tried changing parameters, but without success. Unfortunately, I deleted the original, good segmentation files, so I cannot share, but they were consistent with the segmentation examples I have seen on youtube tutorials.

Input parameters:

```
{ ‘in’ : ‘/Volumes/Drive/QGIS_Files/Personal_Projects/Project/MUL-of-2023-06-20T210559091Z-orthophoto.tif’, ‘filter’ : ‘meanshift’, ‘filter.meanshift.spatialr’ : 5, ‘filter.meanshift.ranger’ : 15, ‘filter.meanshift.thres’ : 0.1, ‘filter.meanshift.maxiter’ : 100, ‘filter.meanshift.minsize’ : 100, ‘mode’ : ‘vector’, ‘mode.vector.out’ : ‘/Volumes/Drive/QGIS_Files/Personal_Projects/Project/Segmentation.shp’, ‘mode.vector.outmode’ : ‘ulco’, ‘mode.vector.inmask’ : None, ‘mode.vector.neighbor’ : True, ‘mode.vector.stitch’ : True, ‘mode.vector.minsize’ : 1, ‘mode.vector.simplify’ : 0.1, ‘mode.vector.layername’ : ‘’, ‘mode.vector.fieldname’ : ‘’, ‘mode.vector.tilesize’ : 1024, ‘mode.vector.startlabel’ : 1, ‘mode.vector.ogroptions’ : ‘’, ‘outputpixeltype’ : 5 }

2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: Default RAM limit for OTB is 256 MB
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: GDAL maximum cache size is 819 MB
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: OTB will use at most 4 threads
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO): Loading metadata from official product
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: Use threaded Mean-shift segmentation.
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: Use 8 connected neighborhood.
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: Simplify the geometry.
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO) Segmentation: Large scale segmentation mode which output vector data
2023-06-21 09:34:21 (INFO): Estimation will be performed in 9 blocks of 976x976 pixels
Computing meanshift segmentation: 100% [] (17s)
2023-06-21 09:34:38 (INFO) Segmentation: Stream size: [976, 976]
2023-06-21 09:34:38 (INFO) Segmentation: Segmentation done, stiching polygons …
Stitching polygons: 100% [] (0s)
2023-06-21 09:34:39 (INFO) Segmentation: REPACK the Shapefile …
Execution completed in 17.64 seconds
Results:
{‘mode.vector.out’: ‘/Volumes/SSD/QGIS_Files/Personal_Projects/LDB_Home/Segmentation.shp’}
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm ‘Segmentation’ finished
```

[image]

I found that when I process an RGB ortho I get better results (still some lines in the segments). So this might help clarity the question/issue. Why can't I get these results with a multispectral-band ortho (NIR-R-G)?

[image]

**Update**:
I have been using WebODM to create my multispectral orthos (imagery taken by a Mavic 3M). I found that when I processed the imagery under 'default' instead of under 'multispectral' I was able to properly segment the resulting multispectral ortho. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Below is the segmented photo, still showing some geometric lines that are problematic.

[image]

Comment: The meanshift filtering is tightly linked to the magnitude of the pixels values. Did you have compared the pixels values distributions between your images? I don't know what is the difference between 'default' and 'multispectral' or your pre-processsing but I would bet that it changes the image values (and/or the number of bands, e.g. for true color rendering in 8 bits). Try changing the `filter.meanshift.ranger` and `filter.meanshift.thresh` parameters.